# how to modify SingleChildScrollView scrolling Edge behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm talking about this effect it's off design so I'd like to remove it or someway to modify it
[image: screenshot]

I tried all the `SingleChildScrollView` constructor parametars but none off them seem to work

Comment: have to tried set :  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(), Or as comment above me mention?